# Typescript array push new objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code:

```
this.restarray.forEach(element => {                     
    element.forEach(elt => {
        let restallx = {name: elt.name, xval: elt.value};
        this.restall.push(restallx);            
        console.log(elt.name);
        console.log(this.restall);
    });
});
```

When I print `elt.name` I get multiple name's, but when i print `this.restall` I get only last name and value. Anyone have idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Declare restall gobally

Comment: what's stored in `restarray`?

Comment: @SantoshJadi, it is declared globally.  e.g.: public restall:Array<any>=[];

Comment: Try to declare it like restall: Array[] = []; Hope it works

Comment: @santoshjadi, it work's, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `restall: Array[] = [];` globally.